# Adding multiple lines of text to a Canvas more easily

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, text

Im trying to add alot of text to a canvas, and I want them to go down vertically. But there is too much text to keep adding `w.create_text()` and replacing the positions and text everytime, it would take an eternity. Is there an easier way that I can basically copy and paste the text from the original file to my code and have it positioned correctly?

Here is the code im working with:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk


def validateLogin(password):
    print(password.get())
    if password.get() == "test":
        master = Tk()
        canvas_width = 1920
        canvas_height = 1080
        w = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        w.create_text(20, 20, text="Hi23")
        w.create_text(20, 40, text="Hi41")
        w.create_text(20, 60, text="Hi51")
        w.create_text(20, 80, text="Hi61")
        w.create_text(20, 100, text="Hi")
        w.create_text(20, 120, text="Hi71")
        w.create_text(20, 140, text="Hi7")
        w.create_text(20, 160, text="Hi1")
        w.create_text(20, 180, text="Hi2")
        w.create_text(20, 200, text="Hi9")
        w.create_text(20, 220, text="Hi8")
        w.create_text(20, 240, text="Hi3")
        w.create_text(20, 260, text="Hi2")
        w.create_text(20, 280, text="Hi2")
        w.pack()
        tkWindow.destroy()
        mainloop()

    if password.get() != "test":
        Label(tkWindow, text="Wrong password!", fg='red').grid(row=5, column=2)


# window
tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('250x100')
tkWindow.title('Passwords')

# password label and password entry box
Label(tkWindow, text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
password = StringVar()
Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password,
      show='*').grid(row=1, column=2)

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, password)

# login button
Button(tkWindow, text="Login",
       command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=2)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

(I used "Hi" as an example)

list of words:

```
words = ["AxsorVayne", "XayahMainz", "axsor123", "AxsorLee", "Axssor", "MSFZed123", "axsor111", "Axsor123", "AxsorAshe", "axsor112", "Axsorr1233", "axsor667", "snqw", "1593", "roxxstar", "Warz", "Valsmurf", "12.august", "PBE", "League Of legends", "OSU", "Axsor", "DAUNTLESS", "EPIC  GAMES", "TAPPED OUT", "Mega", "Ups", "Unity", "SpMEO"]
```

Comment: Maybe loop through it?

Comment: @CoolCloud I don't think I can loop through it because the text is going to be different. I would still have to replace the text one by one.

Comment: Make a list of all the text? and then loop through that list?

Comment: @CoolCloud I added the list of words I need added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the list in the main block:

```
words = ["AxsorVayne", "XayahMainz", "axsor123", "AxsorLee", "Axssor", "MSFZed123", "axsor111", "Axsor123", "AxsorAshe", "axsor112", "Axsorr1233", "axsor667", "snqw", "1593", "roxxstar", "Warz", "Valsmurf", "12.august", "PBE", "League Of legends", "OSU", "Axsor", "DAUNTLESS", "EPIC  GAMES", "TAPPED OUT", "Mega", "Ups", "Unity", "SpMEO"]
```

Then make the loop such that:

```
w = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
count = 20
for word in words: 
    w.create_text(60, count, text=word)
    count += 20
w.pack()
```

Yes you can play around with the numbers and adjust according to what you like, but here is a small way on how I would proceed, if i were to do this.

**TIP:**

- It is better to remove the second `Tk()` and use `Toplevel()`. In this way, you should also remove the `mainloop()` and the `tkWindow.destroy()`. Having more than one `Tk()` will cause many errors later on.

  ```
  master = Toplevel()
  ```

Hope this helped you clear your doubt, do let me know if any errors.

Cheers